# OpenShift use import-image to result into custom image tag

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to import image from docker repository and tag it with custom tag. Found a command `import-image` but it results image with tag **latest**

(example command: `oc import-image docker-repo --from=target-image-with-tag --confirm=true`)

Is there other `oc` commands I could use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage for `oc import-image` is documented as follows:

```
oc import-image IMAGESTREAM[:TAG] [flags]
```

As you do not specify a tag for the ImageStream, "latest" is used. So try something like:

```
oc import-image docker-repo:mytag --from=target-image-with-tag --confirm=true
```

Comment: Great, that's what I've been looking for. Thanks Simon.